# Mysql - Result set not as expected in finding difference between two numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image]

Expected output is positive number but got negative difference despite of giving highest number - lowest number.

Comment: you can't use columns that way , you can use user defined variables or use the original code

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `new price` in usual quotes is a **string**, and subtracting a numeric value from that **string** might result in unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. You can't use a derived column like `new price` to perform any
   calculations
2. Don't use single quotes to enclose column names/alaises. You can safely use backticks.
   A column like `'new price'` when used to perform numeric calculations is evaluated as `0` because it is considered as the string literal `'new price'`.

So your code can be written like this:

```
SELECT name,
       unit_price,
       unit_price * 1.1 AS `new price`, 
       unit_price * 1.1 - unit_price AS `diff price`,  -- or unit_price * 0.1 AS `diff price`
FROM products
```